# Machine learning for discovering formulas

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, software

I have a vector of desired values that I want to fit based in some generated predictors. The tricky part is that I wish to have the explicit formula. For example, giving the below input I would like to get the following formula

Input:

```
Y=[1,2,3,6,7]
X=[1,2,3,4,5;0,0,0,1,1]
```

Output:

```
Transf={'multiply',1,'transform',linear;...
'multiply',2,'transform',linear}

Y=Transf(X) %which would be equal to: Y=1*X(1,:)+2*X(2,:)
```

This is a not so complicated linear regression. but generalizing it could give, log transforms, sin, cosin, roots, exponents.

What software  could I start with? Or how might I implement this?

Comment: Could you clarify what it is that you mean by "explicit formula to access to what extent it makes sense"? Makes sense in what way? And what is it that you want to generalize to give logs, exponentials, etc?

Comment: @rocinante I edited the question. I hope is more clear now.

Comment: for example one idea would be to define every transformation allowed and run a GA to get the best combination. yet, I would guess this is really non-efficient

Comment: Did you see [Eureqa](http://www.nutonian.com/products/eureqa/)?

Comment: @Aksakal I did not known it existed as I had not been able to formulate the search. It seems it is called symbolic regression. I will try it and come back to this point if it makes sense.

Comment: @Aksakal apparently some progress has been made towards a free alternative: http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/14818/seeking-a-free-symbolic-regression-software

Comment: @Aksakal I tried eureqa which is a solution to my problem. yet I had some problems constraining the size of the solution. I will give it a go again in the next few days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to nice answer by @DankMasterDan (+1), I would like to share further information on the topic. It seems that an approach that you're looking for is [symbolic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_regression). It seems to be closely associated with and usually is implemented via *evolutionary algorithms*, such as the most popular *genetic programming* (GP). However, other approaches are also proposed, especially in relation to *analytical models* of physical systems. For example, see a paper by Shmidt and Lipson (2009), published in Science. By the way, [this small open source Java-based project](http://github.com/pkoperek/hubert) presents an implementation of the above-mentioned approach.

In terms of **software**, available for *symbolic regression*, before I concentrate on my favorite open source solutions, I'd like to mention that *Eureqa* is definitely an interesting product, which [has grown from an open source project](http://www.ams.org/notices/201306/rnoti-p713.pdf). However it is quite expensive, as many commercial statistical or machine learning solutions, available on the market today.

I will start a brief review of **open source solutions** with a *hybrid solution* [GPTIPS](http://sites.google.com/site/gptips4matlab), which is an open source plug-in software for commercial MATLAB. It is referred to by authors as a "symbolic data mining platform for MATLAB".

Now, turning to a **full open source software**, we can find several IMHO very interesting solutions. A well-known language-agnostic (but still Python-based) system [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org) offers symbolic regression functionality via [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org) Python library, which can also be used independently as well. Another very interesting comprehensive open source software system is .NET-based [HeuristicLab](http://dev.heuristiclab.com). While HeuristicLab is labeled "a framework for heuristic and evolutionary algorithms", it offers a much wider range of functionality beyond symbolic computations and evolutionary/GP solutions.

In addition to already-mentioned SymPy libarary, **Python ecosystem** offers [DEAP](https://github.com/DEAP/deap) open source project, where DEAP abbreviation refers to Distributed Evolutionary Algorithms in Python.

My brief analysis of open source software for symbolic regression and related solutions would be incomplete without mentioning what my favorite **R ecosystem** offers in that regard. An interesting R package for GP and symbolic regression is `rgp` ([available on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgp)), which is referred to as "R genetic programming framework" (RGP). The RGP package is a part of a larger set of open source tools for symbolic computation in R, developed under the umbrella of a larger [Rsymbolic project](http://rsymbolic.org). There are also several optimization-focused GP packages (http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), however it is highly unlikely that they offer symbolic regression functionality out-of-the-box, as RGP package does.

**References**

Schmidt, M., & Lipson, H. (2009). Distilling free-form natural laws from experimental data. *Science, 324*(5923), 81–85. doi:10.1126/science.1165893 Retrieved from http://creativemachines.cornell.edu/sites/default/files/Science09_Schmidt.pdf

Comment: this answer provides a good overview of the solutions to the problem above. I did tried Eureqa which is definitely a solution for my problem (yet did not really gave what I wished). As I am a MATLAB programmer I will try the GPTIPS to see whether I have more flexibility in defining constraints

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro: I'm glad you liked my answer and found it helpful. Good luck with GPTIPS!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your goal is to find an arbitrary function g(:) such that y=g(x).

The answer to your question depends on what you mean by explicit. Specifically, you should note that there are an infinite number of ways to specify any function g(:), for example g(x)=x on -1

If by 'explicit' you mean find a a g*(:) which is functionally equivalent to g(x) - ie gives the same output of g(x) for all values of x then yes, there are many ML algorithms which can do this for arbitrary functions g(:). These algorithms could give you perfect predictive power from x to y, albeit at the possible expense of overfitting the data. They include SVM with RBF kernels and decision trees (ie any algorithm w/ infinite VK dimension).

However, if by explicit you mean the SIMPLEST g(:) which describes y=g(x), then things get much more complicated because simplicity/sparsity/complexity is a human notion which can only be quantified very clumsily.  For example, in theory, SVM regression w/ rbf kernel could perfectly fit y=sin(x), but it wouldn't output g=sin(:) but rather an uninterpretable series of coefficients, and you would have to do the work to piece them together into 'sin(x)'.

Now done with that theoretical mumbo-jumbo, I think a good way of getting started is to fit the the data with a taylor expansion as this is at least somewhat interpretable.

Good luck, hope this helps!

Comment: definitely a number of functions will be able to match y. yet, if one constrains the length of the solution less options will be available. what i meant is what is described as symbolic regression.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly prefer *Mathematica* for such tasks.  Given data of the form $mydata = \{ \{ x_1, y_1 \}, \{ x_2, y_2 \}, ... \}$, one searches for the unknown parameters such as $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ in a non-linear function of your choice in this way:

```
NonlinearModelFit[mydata, {a + b x + c x^2 + d Sin[x]}, {a, b, c, d}, x]
```

The symbolic output is

```
FittedModel[2.8 + 1.075 x + .292 x^2 + 4.9 Sin[x]]
```

A plot of that nonlinear model and the data looks like this:

[image]

You can put in as many basis functions as you like, and some may be "fit" with $0$ coefficients and such.  Of course, too, you need more data points than free parameters for your fit to be meaningful.

Comment: _Mathematica_ is definitely a nice piece of software. However, it's rather expensive. For those, who can't afford it, is cost-conscious or simply prefer open source solutions :-), _SageMath_, which, among other options, I've mentioned in my answer, seems to be a reasonable alternative.

Comment: The student version of *Mathematica* isn't too expensive.  My view is that if a software tool makes you 10% more efficient than another (and *Mathematica* makes me 50% more efficient than other tools), then it is worth it.  But of course, everyone has different values and desires.

Comment: I don't pay much attention to student versions of software, as their lower prices are just a fast road to a vendor lock-in. However, I understand your point and agree with you on this. Sometimes, it makes sense to prefer less open solutions, if they offer enough benefits versus alternatives.

Comment: I think this is solution misleads the reader. Any routines that solves a non-linear least-squares curve fitting problem will do. We did not *discover* anything; eg. why not use `log(x)` or `x^3`. We simply defined a small optimization problem to solve, `R` 's `nls` would do the same, `MATLAB`'s `lsqnonlin` would do the same, `scipy`'s `curve_fit` would do the same. No formula discovery here...

Comment: although i appreciate the idea, in your solution you are already defining the model, and are just looking for the coefficients. that is a rather "trivial" approach. the idea here is that we wish to understand which model it is and its coefficients.

Comment: One always approaches such a problem with a prior (explicit or implicit) about the basis functions one wishes to consider.  Are you really accepting as candidates Ackerman's function, or Hypergeometric function, the inverse of the Jacobi Elliptic Function, the derivative of the even Mathieu function, and so on?  Even genetic programming methods require the modeler to provide a set of basis functions.  In the approach I outlined, you can specify a larger set than will ultimately be found, and hence is hardly "trivial" at all.  In fact, it is the technique used by experts.

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro One can put in as many basis functions as one likes, and if the data doesn't support significant contribution of a particular basis component, then the fit will return 0 (or $,\epsilon$) for that component.  In this way one prunes away from a large function set the irrelevant components.  For the "objectors" to this approach:  State a method *even in principle* that would find (or deduce) a model that wasn't implicitly in the model database ahead of time.  I do not believe you can.  Certainly not the genetic programming approach.  Once you realize this, the issue is closed.

Comment: @David G. Stork The problem here I would say is that you need to define every single component of the model. Lets say that you have a square function. your model will never be able to model this as you would need to define infinite number of sines such that the model would be able to fit every one. yet in a GA, if you allow it to use sines (note here that you did not define how many), it will keep adding then and reducing the error. Even in the example you gave, if you had one higher frequency sin there, you would never be able to fit it properly (without the user knowing it existed).

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro  You are right.  You must express--explicitly or implicitly--the bases for your fit.  In some cases that can be done simply (all polynomials of the form $\sum a_i x^i$).  But there is simply no other way.  What other way can you even *imagine*?

Comment: as said before you can define general basis functions that genetic algorithms can use (for example you define  a*sin(x)). by evolution processes different combinations will be tested, this mean in one iteration you can have 1*sin(10), in another 1*sin(10x)+1*sin(100x), and in another 1*sin(10x)+3*sin(100x)+5*sin(37x). here we defined only a*sin(b*x) and the method returned 3 combinations of sines that approximate the function. in the approach you showed we would need right at the beginning saying that the model was composed of a1*sin(b1*x)+a2*sin(b2*x)+a3*sin(b3*x).

Comment: in truth the best approach is probably the one that combines both these approaches. you first choose a model based in GA, then optimize it,then determine a new model based in evolution processes.

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro the GA approach you mention is not fundamentally different from the basis set approach.  You have "available" `Sin[a x]` for different *a*s and continually increase the number of *a*s.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork this thread is starting to be too large so I will just reply once more. you do also have basis functions as discussed. yet the chosen of the next model is entirely different. in your case if you had 2 models entirely different yet with a reasonable fit how would you join both? you would give all the basis of one and another and start from scratch? GA does has a set of better rules for that, so it does not start from the beginning in every turn. Yes you could join your models differently and improve, but now it starts to be a bit different from the presented solution.

Comment: @ASantosRibeiro Yes.  This discussion is extending too long so I too will reply just once more.  I see no substantive difference between traditional model fitting using a basis set yielding a low coefficient to a component and a GA that includes the same component "late" in evolution (and, presumably, with a small coefficient).  It isn't clear that fewer components means "more interpretable" model.  A traditional model consisting of ten harmonic components may be easily interpretable (e.g., acoustics) while a GA gives just 3 very complicated, unrelated components.  Which would you prefer?