# Can supervised machine learning techniques infer the formula (if it exists) for a statistical model?

Tags: machine-learning, inference

Suppose that we have response data $y_i$ generated by a specific mathematical function $y_i=\mathcal{F}(X_i)+e_i$ where $X_i$ is a vector of predictor variables with random error term $e_i$. Without any prior knowledge of the function that generates the response observations, is it possible to accurately infer the form and parameters of $\mathcal{F}(X_i)$ using supervised machine learning algorithms such as gradient boosting, artificial neural networks, or other suitable techniques?

For example, let's generate random observations according to a nonlinear function $\mathcal{F}(X_i)$ which would be difficult to infer with a parametric statistical models such as linear least squares regression:

$y_i=\frac{\beta_1 x_{1i}+\beta_2sin(e^{\beta_3 x_{2i}})}{\beta_4^{x_{3i}}}+e_i$,

where $x_{ki}\sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$ and $e_i\sim N(0,1)$.

While building an accurate predictive model $f(X_i)$ would certainly be useful, are there machine learning tools that allow us to go a step further and accurately infer the actual function $\mathcal{F}(X_i)$?

Comment: I give you pairs of points $(x_i,y_i)$. Can you infer the function they came from? Of course not. The only thing you can do is suggest functions with some regularization on how much you want to over/under fit your points. For example suppose I give you points $(n,1)$ for $n=0,1,2,\cdots$. Then you could guess $y=\cos(2\pi x )$ or $y=1$.

Comment: @AlexR. What about a simple nonlinear case - if I give you orbital coordinates for an asteroid, is there a machine learning technique that could infer that an elliptical formula is the best-fitting function for the data?

Comment: @RobertF like AlexR said, you are implicitly assuming a particular regularization method. There are in infinite number of curves that perfectly fit the data f or planetary motion.

Comment: @Bey Right, a particular curve could be chosen based on minimizing a loss function, or predictive accuracy on a holdout dataset. But is it a fool's dream to ask if it's possible to fit a boosting algorithm, for example, to a dataset and then translate the boosting model to a mathematical function? In a sense, translate a predictive model to an explanatory model.

Comment: @RobertF once again, you'll be faced with HOW to translate the fitted ML model to a "nice" mathematical function. Technically, you already have a mathematical function embedded in the fitted ML model. You'll need to do choose yet another regularization scheme to find what type of models you want to fit.

Comment: @Bey The "How" is the big question. Actually this question is close to what I'm asking & discusses *symbolic regression*: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140354/machine-learning-for-discovering-formulas.

Comment: @RobertF that is a cool approach. Probably the closest you will come to what you are looking for.  It reminded me of this: http://www.wired.com/2009/04/newtonai/